# Merge Replication Optimization

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am running Merge Replication on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 through web sync.

Is there a way to recognize when regenerating a new snapshot and applying it would be more efficient than running a merge?

For instance my system has a way that a user can change settings to determine which data each subscriber receives. This won't happen often, but if it does then millions of `INSERTs` could be sent to the subscriber representing the new data.

Is there a way to say "hey, I have over a million updates, actually recreate a new snapshot and apply it instead"?